# Sharepoint 2010, Document Library, Key Filter - "Modified" field filtering is out by one day

Tags: document-library, filter

We have a Sharepoint 2010 farm across 4 servers and added "modfied" as a Key Filter for metadata navigation.  When I select to filter on a specific day I enter a date the filtered results are out by one day, I actually have to enter the next day in the filter to find the correct items I want. E.g. to filter items modifed on 20/07/2010 I need to enter 21/07/2010 to get the results I want.

For each item the "Modified" column is showing the correct timestamp for the date/time the file was modified, so why isn't it returing the correct timestamp when I try to use the Key Filter?
However 2 observations.

1. If there is more than a page of results, scrolling forward a page then back a page delivers the correct results.
2. If you remove the column from key filters then open the menu for the Modified Column Heading you can filter correctly on the dates.

All Servers and Sites or set the same regional Settings.

Yours Hopefully

Ross

Answer (score 3):

What I have found is that if Sharepoint is set to (UTC) Greenwich Mean Time but the servers are set to (UTC) Coordinated Time instead of (UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London. Then the Key Filters displays the correct result. It is almost as though GMT + Our Daylight Saving Time is throwing it 2 hours out instead of 1. Cheers Ross